# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen: How to customize the "scroll down arrow" Javascript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll

WordPress' Twenty Seventeen theme comes bundled with a small arrow on the bottom-right of the screen who's class is `menu-scroll-down`. It makes a smooth scrolling effect to the content. I'd like to customize the scrolling speed.

I've found the JavaScript file in `assets\js\jquery.scrollTo.js`, but I'm not sure I'm at the right place, and I can't seem to make the changes I want. I can't find where in the JavaScript is the `.menu-scroll-down` class mentioned, either.

Does anyone know where to change these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `global.js` that is in the same directory as `assets\js\jquery.scrollTo.js` then find the following code

```
$menuScrollDown.click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( window ).scrollTo( '#primary', {
            duration: 600,
            offset: { top: menuTop - navigationOuterHeight }
    });
});
```

and then change the `duration` to change the scroll speed.

https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyseventeen/1.4/assets/js/global.js#L200

Comment: and after any updates you'll need to change that part